# How to locate the checkboxes with the attribute checked

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, checkbox, css-selectors

I have a list of checkboxes and I need to find the checkboxes that have the attribute "checked". Below is how my check box element looks,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="u-display--inline-block u-margin-right--small" checked="">
```

How can I find this with xpath? I cannot use //input[@type='checkbox' and @checked='true')] because i don't have a checked value true attribute. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just mention the attribute `checked` to test if it exists:

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @checked]
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use below xpath for the same:

```
//input[@type='checkbox'  and @checked]
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the *checkboxes* that have the attribute `checked` you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  "input.u-display--inline-block.u-margin-right--small[type='checkbox'][checked]"
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  "//input[@class='u-display--inline-block u-margin-right--small' and @type='checkbox'][@checked]"
  ```